# How do I get my SQL database to attach to “All in One WP Migration” plugin? Also how do I stop my domain from multiplying?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, hosting, cpanel

I need a little help. So I’m having trouble with transferring my last website over to my cPanel. I am trying to point the domain back to the old cPanel so I can access the existing website. When I try to point it back, GoDaddy is making copies of the domain and I don’t understand why. Also, I love the “All in One Migration” plugin! I got my 3rd and 4th website literally in 20 minutes. However, for my 5th website, when I try exporting, the files attach but my SQL database doesn’t. How can I fix this? Thank you

Renaming the database, made a new one.

Answer (score 0):

basically when you use the wordpress as your cms to manage your website. wordpress has the tables in database that stores the site url or your domain .

when you copy your wordpress cms fo another domain you should change the domain in database tables . if you dont, then by entering the new URL in browser you will redirect to old domain by wordpress .

you can change domain in database by runing some SQL Queries :

```html
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```